# Make cURL call/ping itself forever

Tags: php, rest, curl, cron, timeout

I have some problems with timeout on my host. And I have this script that takes sometime to end and will probably take longer as the database gets larger.

So I thought about a solution that every hour a cron will start this script, and everytime the script takes longer than N seconds, it will stop where it is (after the current loop interation) and call itself (send a post to that URL that should restart the proccess).

But I have to make sure it calls itself until all the job is finished (I use some flags on database).

So I made a few tests where my scripts should add 1 to the number currently in a file and save it to that file. Then it waits for 2 seconds and call itself.

I realized the number stops increasing after 20 or maybe 40 interactions and the number never gets higher than this.

How can I make a PHP file be called forever until I say it's enough?

This is my script right now:

```
function callItself(){
    $curl = curl_init();
    $post = array('run'=>true);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,SITE_URL.'/'.CRON_SCRIPT);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'api');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 10);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);

    curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
}
```

@edit

this is my `callItself` function. the rest of the script is just a command to write a file and a `sleep`.